# Add URL field to the link post format

Tags: customization, post-formats

I'm building a blog where 95% of posts will be of "link" post format.

I'd like to specify the URL explicitly when adding a new "link" post.
In a separate field between the title and the content. (Not taken as a first link from the content as Twenty Thirteen does by default)

What is the best way to achieve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In *twentythirteen* theme, the post format link is shown using the `content-link.php` file. The part that displays the link is:

```
<h1 class="entry-title">
<a href="<?php echo esc_url(twentythirteen_get_link_url());?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
</h1>
```

So the link is shown using the `twentythirteen_get_link_url()`; this function uses the wp function `get_url_in_content()` to get the first link in the content and shows it if there is one, if not it shows the the post permalink.

Unlikely, these functions have no filter to the result, so to change this behavior you have 2 options:

1. edit the theme file
2. create a child theme

The suggested solution is the second. In `wp-content/themes` folder create a folder named `twentythirteen-child` and inside it put 2 files. The first is the `style.css` that can contain just the required content:

```
/*
 Theme Name:     Twenty Thirteen Child
 Author:         You
 Template:       twentythirteen
*/

@import url('../twentythirteen/style.css');
```

Now go to your dashboard and find this new created child theme and activate it. Visiting the site you'll not see any change.

Now copy the `content-link.php` file from the twentythirteen theme folder to your child theme folder. Find the code I posted above (should be lines 13-15).

Replace with this:

```
<h1 class="entry-title">
  <?php $link = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_my_custom_link', true); ?>
  <a href="<?php echo $link ? esc_url($link) ? esc_url(twentythirteen_get_link_url()); ?>">
    <?php the_title(); ?>
  </a>
</h1>
```

Save it.

Now you can add an hidden custom field `'_my_custom_link'` to the post and this will be used as url for the post.

Being a hidden field (the key starts with `'_'`) normally you have added a metabox for it, but once you want display after the title in the post edit screen you can use `'edit_form_after_title'` action hook to display the field and 'save_post' hook to save it.

When diplaying the field be sure that the post type is 'post', and the post format is empty (new post or no post format) or is equal to 'link'.

So, add a `functions.php` file in the newly created child theme, and in this file add:

```
add_action('edit_form_after_title', 'my_url_form_field');
add_action('save_post', 'my_url_form_field_save');

function my_url_form_field( $post ) {
  if ( $post->post_type != 'post') return;
  $format = get_post_format($post->ID);
  if ( ! empty($format) && ($format != 'link') ) return;
  ?>
  <div id="urlwrap">
  <p>
  <label for="post-link-url"><strong>URL:</strong></label>
  <input type="text" class="large-text" name="_my_custom_url" size="30" value="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, '_my_custom_url', true); ?>" id="post-link-url" autocomplete="off" />
  </p>
  </div>
  <?php
}

function my_url_form_field_save( $postid ) {
  if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE );
  if ( isset($_POST['_my_custom_url']) ) {
    if (( strpos($_POST['_my_custom_url'], 'http://') !== 0 ) && (strpos($_POST['_my_custom_url'], 'https://') !== 0 ))
      $_POST['_my_custom_url'] = 'http://' . $_POST['_my_custom_url'];
    $url = filter_var($_POST['_my_custom_url'], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) ? $_POST['_my_custom_url'] : '';
    update_post_meta($postid, '_my_custom_url', $url);
  }
}
```

Preview or what you'll get:

[image: preview]

Now that you get it works, you can customize `content-link.php` in your child theme as you want.

When twentythirteen gets an update, you can update it with no fear: your changes are secure in the child theme.

Comment: Hi GM, thanks for the answer. I can display a custom field, but the main issue is: 1) how to display a "URL" field (without the need to choose it from a drop down) on the "new post" page and 2) how to put it between the title and the content on the "new post" page

Comment: Hi @MichałPękała see the edit.